# What is the difference between Consumes.For, Consumes.Selected, Consumes.All and Consumes.Context in MassTransit?

Tags: masstransit

I've started looking at MassTransit and am writing the classes that will handle the messages. When I implement the interface from `Consumes<T>` I get four options: `All`, `Selected`, `For<T>` and `Context`. What is the difference between the four and when should them be used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`All` just gives you all the messages to consume. `Context` is All but you also get the `Context<TMessage>` if you need it. `Selected` allows you to accept or reject messages before it gets to your consumer. `For<T>` is primarily for Sagas, I don't think there's a good use case for it outside of that.

Starting off, just using `All` is likely the right answer.